# Do I need to add many methods, or is it possible to call one method

Tags: java, android, logic

I have a tic tac toe app, and I want to know whether it is possible to set all the tic tac toe buttons to one on_click event, and then create a variable to get the ID of the button clicked, then pass it as a parameter to another method which will do the actual functionality, OR do I need to create different on_click events for each button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this, and add as many "cases" as needed:

```
View.OnClickListener sharedClickHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View view) {
      switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
          // handle first button
          break;
        case R.id.button2:
          // handle second button
          break;

      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use one listener - the [`onClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html#onClick(android.view.View)) method takes a `View` parameter, which is the view that was clicked on. You can then find out which of your buttons that was:

```
View.OnClickListener sharedClickHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    // Do the right thing based on the ID
  }
}
```

Exactly how you do what you need to do based on the ID is up to you. For simple examples you could just use a switch/case statement; in other cases if you're mapping from ID to something else (a mutable object representing game state for example) you could use a `Map<Integer, GameObject>` and just get the right one...

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show how this could be done with some example code?

Comment: @LightMikeE: Well you can just call `getId()` on the view to find out which it is...

Comment: thing is, i get an error saying incompatible types, requires java.lang.String found int

Comment: @LightMikeE: Ah yes, I'd forgotten that the IDs ended up as integers. Will edit.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but Ofer Lando gave the example code with switch cases, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

hello you can use the same click event for button, you can attach for example an integer as a tag to the button so that you can know which button was clicked and handle accordingly.

```
button1.setTag(1);
button2.setTag(2);
button3.setTag(3);


button1.setOnClickListener(buttonClick());
button2.setOnClickListener(buttonClick());
button3.setOnClickListener(buttonClick());



 public View.OnClickListener buttonClick(){

    View.OnClickListener click = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int numberClicked = v.getTag();

            //You have now the button clicked

        }
    };


    return click;

}
```